# on click change next TD table

Tags: javascript, css, html, onclick, html-table

I want to make a table that when we click a box it unclock next column one.

I made this work with two tds and it works, but when I replicate it it doesnt work.

My ideias where, If I have a TD that has a class (can be cliqued), then the java script will allow us to click there and change next tds or even next column class to be clicked like the one before and changes that class to a non clickable one so we dont click there again.

My code for 2 tds is this one:

```
            <td>
                <div style="position: relative;" class="can-select1">
                    <img src="http://lkimg.zamimg.com/images/guides/ability-marker.png" style="vertical-align: middle;" class="can-select">
                    <div class="can-select-text">1</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div style="position: relative;" class="nothing1">
                    <img src="http://lkimg.zamimg.com/images/guides/ability-marker.png" style="vertical-align: middle;" class="nothing">
                    <div class="can-select-text">2</div>
                </div>
            </td>
```

JS:

```
$('.can-select1').click(function(e){
    $(this).addClass("is-selected");
    $(this).find('.can-select').addClass("is-selected");
    $(this).children('.can-select-text').addClass("is-selected");
    var nextTd;
    nextTd=$(this).parent().find('.nothing1');
    nextTd.find('.nothing').addClass("can-select1");
    nextTd.addClass("can-select1");
    nextTd.removeClass('nothing1')
});
```

CSS:

```
.can-select1 {
    cursor:pointer;
    opacity:0.4;
}
.can-select-text{
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 32px;
    font: bold 13px/32px 'Trebuchet Ms';
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); color: #111;
}
.is-selected {
    cursor:default;
    opacity:1.0;
}

.nothing1{
    cursor:default;
    opacity:0;
}
```

JSFIDDLE for 2 td: http://jsfiddle.net/p3Q7Z/5/

JSFiddle for table: http://jsfiddle.net/p3Q7Z/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't watch for your first code (working), just for your the second (not working).

I have to change the line.

```
nextTd=$(this).parent().find('.nothing1');
```

to

```
nextTd=$(this).parent().next().find('.nothing1');
```

Just it.

That is, `parent()` reaches the first 'td'; `next()` reaches the second, where you can find the element with the specified class.

Comment: And, yes, I have to say you should write your code in a so much clear way.

`nothing`, `nothing1`, `can-select`, `can-select1`, `can-select-text`... is a messy. You should be able to write this code with one or two control classes. But that's not the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the next TD with `.next()` : http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: I dont get how to select the TD instead of everything else.